# installing appflower on xampp for linux

Tags: xampp

I've been trying to figure out this problem for a while now and I thought I'd ask it here on stackexchange in case somebody out there has tried this and successfully got it to work.

I'm trying to install a RAD webapp tool called AppFlower through Xampp for Linux.

I am also experiencing issues with the command below:

symfony afs:init
symfony: command not found

This is the final command used to start up the AppFlower Studio dev environment, but this command doesn't work.

I have tried using:

./symfony afs:init
Same error as above

php ./symfony afs:init
gives a php error saying it isn't installed, but this is Xampp for Linux, so that command won't apply

/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini ./symfony afs:init
it will give a permission denied error, but even with 'sudo' in front, it says 'command not found'

The solution posted on the appflower forum is for xampp itself, but the problem I have is that they use the php.exe command to run the 'symfony afs:init' command, which xampp for linux doesn't have. The closest thing I could think of was to use the php.ini file, but (as seen above) that doesn't work.

Hopefully somebody can assist regarding this issue.

Regards,

Note. The process to run appflower on a manual version of lamp (one in which php, mysql, apache are all downloaded separately) is a lot more complex and the xampp installation is supposed to be much easier (in fact it is) but at the last point of this installation, this 'symfony afs:init' command is the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Linux, why not install AppFlower directly. It's pretty straightforward, maybe i lost something on the way, understanding why you use XAMMP for Linux.

Installation instructions for AppFlower on Ubuntu, 
http://www.appflower.com/doc/1_2/learn_install_git_on_ubuntu

Comment: I'm currently using a xampp for linux version of a server on my linux system. Won't installing another apache cause conflicts on my system? But I see that the link you provide is for installing and building via Git, maybe that will work.

Comment: I'm not sure if suggesting this will appeal to you guys at AppFlower, but maybe if you had a limited web-based version of AppFlower that shows exactly how it works, then people can demo it and see for themselves what it is all about. If any of the people are like me, then signing up repeatedly just to test stuff out becomes very irritating, but just being allowed to test a complete demo version (like just putting buttons on) would really be nice and it may also get you a lot more cloud/paying clients that way. Just a suggestion.